# How to Automatically Close a Javascript Accordion when another accordion is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have several accordions in a site I'm designing. Basically the accordions display thumbnail versions of colors that you can click to change the color of a certain element. However, if you click one accordion, then you click another accordion, the colors overlap. I'm trying to make it so when another accordion is clicked, it automatically closes the previous accordion that was open. Here's the code:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
    to highlight the button that controls the panel */
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
      $(".accordion, .big-accordion").accordion({
        event: "mouseover"
      });
      $(".accordion .ui-accordion-header a").css({
        padding: "1px 1px 1px 30px"
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Close all accordions then open the accordion that was clicked.

Comment: Before applying the `active` class to newly opened accordion select the currently active one and close: `$(".accordion.active").closeIt()`. Edit: I am not sure how to close your accordions so I made up a function name for it but I hope you get the idea. I would also check to make sure the newly selected one is also not the currently selected one.